# Adams Bashforth method pi product indices

Tags: numerical-methods

For a certain programming assignment, I have to calculate the b coefficients for the Adams Bashforth method, and to evaluate these involves [this expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddI3G.png). I understand that the pi notation refers to the product of the terms specified by the indices. In my assignment I am given that $$s=7$$

[image]

My confusion is on the bottom indices, where it says that $$i = 0    , i≠j$$ while j is defined by the "for" statement on the right hand side of the image. My logic begins starting with evaluating the first j value, which is 0, but this goes against the above condition that i and j do not equal. In general, how am I to evaluate this for each value of j while satisfying the condition?

Comment: Basically the $i \ne j$ means that "do the product as normal, but skip whatever value $j$ is equal to." So if you're at $j=0$, then the product is just from $i=1$ to $i=s-1$. If you're at $j=3$, you take the product for $i=0$ to $i=2$, skip $i=j=3$, and then continue multiplying through with $i=4$ to $i=s-1$.

Comment: For any value of $j$ in computing the product, you don't include the factor for $i=j$.  So, when $j=0$ you start at $i=1$